# Is 1 hour 15 min layover sufficient at Bankgok airport?

Tags: layovers

I'm planning to book ticket to Saigon from Hyderabad on Thai Airlines. This is my preferable route because the actual airtime is just 6 hours compared to other routes. There is a layover of 1hr 15 min at Suvarnabhoomi airport to catch the flight to Ho Chi Minh City, is that sufficient ? This would be a single ticket on Thai Airlines.

On the other routes via Changi airport KL international airport both airtime and layover are longer.

Comment: One ticket (probably ok) or two separate tickets ( no way) ?

Comment: @Hilmar 1 ticket, updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its one ticket, your baggage will be checked through. You just have to deboard the plane and change the gates. Its more than enough time.

Worst case of delay which causes you to miss the flight, Thai Airways is responsible to rebook on next flight for free and book a hotel for you in case the flight is on next day.

There is two flights per day from BKK to SGN to Thai

https://www.google.com/flights#flt=BKK.SGN.2019-01-30;c:SGD;e:1;a:TG;sd:1;t:f;tt:o